# Why does to register agents return this error: FIPAAgentManagement.MissingParameter?

Tags: java, agents-jade

I want to register several agents.

For doing this I'm using the following code

The clases

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] services = {"-gui"};
    Boot.main(services);
    Agent1 = new Agent1(0,0,"a");
}

}

public class Agent1 extends Agent{

public Agent1(int x, int y, String name) {
        super(x, y, name);
        setup();
    }

protected void setup(){
        System.out.println("hi");
        ServiceDescription sd  = new ServiceDescription();
        sd.setType( "buyer" );
        sd.setName( "asa" );
        register( sd );
    }  

void register( ServiceDescription sd){
            DFAgentDescription dfd = new DFAgentDescription();
            dfd.setName(getAID());
            dfd.addServices(sd);

try {  
    DFService.register(this, dfd );  
}
catch (FIPAException fe) { fe.printStackTrace(); }

}

protected void takeDown(){
        System.out.println("bye");
    }

}
```

But I am getting the following error:

> jade.domain.FIPAAgentManagement.MissingParameter: (missing-parameter
>   df-agent-description name)

How can I fix the error?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not creating the agent correctly. The `getAID()` will return null, and the `DFAgentDescription` becomes invalid.

You should pass `-agents` to `jade.Boot`, and it will create the agent for you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // the agent's name is agent1, change xy.zy to your package
    String[] services = {"-gui", "-agents", "agent1:xy.zy.Agent1"};
    Boot.main(services);
}
```

You don't need `Agent1 = new Agent1(0,0,"a");` and you don't need the constructor in `Agent1`. The method `setup()` is called automatically.